# AFNetworking SessionManager setting HTTPHeaderField cause Error

Tags: ios, afnetworking

In the subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager, before invoking a GET method, I have the following:

```
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:userName forHTTPHeaderField:@"aaa"];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"bbb"];
```

Also following were set prior the above header field setters,

```
 self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
 self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

When I invoke the GET, I received following in my debug console. Request is not captured in Charles. 
Here is how I invoked the call, nothing special:

```
 [self GET:@"default" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id    
        responseObject){
        if ([self.delegate        
     respondsToSelector:@selector(PoDMongooseLoginManager:didAuthenticate:)])   
        { 
            //success code
        }
    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
           {

              //
           }
         }
```

[image]

However the request is issued without problem when the setters for the HttpHeaderField were commented out.

Please help.. I had set custom httpHeader before without problems, but it was on AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post if you are calling

```
self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

before or after setting the headers with

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:userName forHTTPHeaderField:@"aaa"];
[self.requestSerializer setValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"bbb"];
```

If you set `self.requestSerializer` to `AFJSONRequestSerializer` after setting the headers, then you are squashing those headers you just set.

Comment: Thank you dmorrow, very good point! However, for my case, the requestSerializer was set before the header fields. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because `userName` or `password` is `nil`? Are you checking for them not being `nil` ?

Comment: Thank you, Armin! They are not nil.

Comment: Could you please paste in the error you get in the console as well? To me it looks like the error is telling you that you're getting a non JSON response from the server. Have you tried the call with Postman or some other API client?

Comment: Armin, there is no JSON response, because it error out before the GET method was invoked. I did not see any logging the Charles, which is the proxy client I use to  introspect the Http Requests. Also everything is fine if I run the Chrom REST Console. Just got error in iOS code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that server returns a string stead of a valid JSON, for some reason the Charles did not catch the request, which misled to think that the request was never fired.